# Change parent property from within emitted child component method in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Inside vue component I have another child component `datatabel` which has emitted method `sort`

```
<datatable @sort="sortBy"></datatable>
```

Currently the emitted `sort` method calls another method `sortBy` in parent component, which then updates a property in the parent.

Is it possible to update the parent property directly form emitted `sort` method?

Something like this:

```
<datatable @sort="parentAttribute = 'value that was emitted'"></datatable>
```

The above example doesn't work, but I am not probably doing it right.

Can that be done, if so, what would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access the event payload with `$event`

```html
<datatable @sort="parentAttribute = $event"/>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Value needs to be passed in this case: `$event.target.value`

Comment: It depends on what was emitted in the first place.